# Make an input string into a list in python

Tags: python

I want to turn the string:

```
avengers,ironman,spiderman,hulk
```

into the list:

```
['avengers','ironman','spiderman','hulk']
```

I tried

```
list = raw_input("Enter string:")
list = list.split()
```

but it's not working the right way as I need it, it's taking the whole string and makes it as one item in the list (it works fine without the "," but that's not what I need)

Comment: `list.split(',')`. But don't use `list` as a variable name; you're overriding a (very useful) built-in function (called `list`).

Comment: @Doorknob冰 alright thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you dont pass anything to split method, it splits on empty space. Pass the comma as argument:

```
my_list.split(',')
```

edited so you dont use list as name

Answer (score 2):

> Hello guys i want to make for example the next string:
>
> ```
> avengers,ironman,spiderman,hulk into the next list:
>
>
> ['avengers','ironman','spiderman','hulk']
> ```
>
> i tried that `
>
> ```
> list = raw_input("Enter string:")
>     list = list.split()
> ```

Do this instead:

```
list = raw_input("Enter string:")
list = list.split(",")
```

And, as mentioned by the others, you might want to not use the name "list" for your string/array.